# PHP dependency property scope

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, scope

In the following class, I have two properties, `$session` and `$client` and these are properties into which dependencies are injected. In the class, they are declared as `public` but is this the correct scope for properties containing dependencies? What is best practice for PHP in this regard, `public`, `protected` or `private`?

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Dummy example class.
 */
namespace App\My\Namespace;

use App\My\Namespace\SessionInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;

/**
 * Class DummyClass
 * @package App\My\Namespace
 */
class DummyClass {

  /**
   * @var \App\My\Namespace\SessionInterface
   */
  public $session;

  /**
   * GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
   */
  public $client;

  /**
   * @param \SessionInterface $session
   * @param \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface $client
   */
  public function __construct(
    SessionInterface $session,
    ClientInterface $client
  ) {
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->client = $client;
  }

}
```

Comment: Set both to `protected` and write getters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set them to private (so they can only be altered in the class itself) and then write getters and setters to access and inject them.

```
private $session;

public function getSession()
{
  return $this->session;
}

public function setSession($new_session)
{
  $this->session = $new_session;
}
```

This is just a way of encapsulating them so that the only way to alter or see the value of the variables are to call these methods. The benefit is that you can do some functionality inside these methods that you couldn't easily do if the variables were public. For instance, say you wanted to make sure `$new_session` was the right data type, you could check before setting it.

You can set them as protected also and for this example they'd behave the same, but you want to do that when you have a class that is inheriting your class and needs to have access to those variables.